# admin last login detail

Tags: admin, security

i admin panel admin can see login customers last login details.
i want to know where can admin check / see his last login i can not find it please guide me .

it is necessary for security purpose

Answer (score 1):

> /app/etc/modules/Company_Logindate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Logindate>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Company_Logindate>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> /app/code/local/Company/Logindate/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Logindate>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Company_Logindate>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <logindate>
                <class>Company_Logindate_Block</class>
            </logindate>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <permissions_user_grid>Company_Logindate_Block_Rewrite_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Grid</permissions_user_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

> /app/code/local/Company/Logindate/Block/Rewrite/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/User/Grid.php

```
<?php

class Company_Logindate_Block_Rewrite_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Grid
{
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        parent::_prepareColumns();

        $this->addColumn('last_login', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Last Login'),
            'index'     => 'logdate'
        ));

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: i had done that where will it show i can not find it ?

Comment: On admin users grid (system / permissions). I checked this on my magento